# Symfony2 populating object with Doctrine results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a Symfony2 API just to learn stuff. What I am trying to achieve is this:

Load templates from DB this is working.
Now I am trying to output retrieved templates from my database in browser and this is where I am struggling.

So my Doctrine is working and retrives the templates, I also created TemplateResponse where I want to populate each construc variable with Doctrine array key => value.

TemplateResponse file:

```
<?php

namespace Boltmail\UserBundle\BoltmailResponse;

class TemplateResponse {

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    public $templates;

    /**
     * @param $templates
     */
    public function __construct(
        $templates
    ){
        $this->templates = $templates;
    }
}
```

TemplateListFactory:

```
<?php

namespace Boltmail\UserBundle\BoltmailFactory;

use Boltmail\UserBundle\BoltmailRepository\TemplateListRepository;
use Boltmail\UserBundle\BoltmailResponse\TemplateResponse;
use Boltmail\UserBundle\BoltmailResponse\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TemplateListFactory {

    public $template;

    public function __construct(
        TemplateListRepository $templateListRepository
    ){
        $this->template = $templateListRepository;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $template = $this->template->searchTemplate();

        if ($template) {
            return new TemplateResponse (
                $template
            );
        } else {
            return new Response(
                false,
                'Something went wrong'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

if ($template) {
    return new TemplateResponse (
        $template->temp_id,
        $template->title,
        $template->content,
        $template->author
```

So I believe Doctrine returns the data as an array I guess and I am trying to access its values as if they were objects that's why I get this error.

I also tried using foreach loop inside If statement before populating TemplateReponse but this also did not work. Any idea how I can make this work.

OK I made some changes and I got the result I was after:

Result:

```
{
  templates: [
   {
      temp_id: "0",
      title: "New Template",
      content: "I am new template blehhhhhh",
      author: "Michael"
   },
   {
      temp_id: "1",
      title: "Liverpool Template",
      content: "You Will Never Walk Alone",
      author: "Bob"
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide searchTemplate implementation?

Comment: please check above changes

Comment: Use some logging function to perform debug. I suppose that you're not performing the right query and your return value is null or a sort of it. Try with get_class($this->template); BTW doctrine will help you without re-inventing the wheel... If you call the method with null parameter, this should raise an exception

Comment: Please check above edits

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to achieve something that already exists inside Symfony: it's called [Doctrine ORM](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

Comment: Sort of I agree I just prefer to use Doctrine DBAL for some reason...... regardless is it possible to achieve what I am trying to ...?

Comment: Yes, it is totally possible but why re-write something that already exists? ;)
Besides, even if you use the ORM, you can always access the underlying DBAL connection.

Comment: @Tomazi: Just for the sake of conversation, what's the reasons behind DBAL choose?

Comment: Ermm i go just to it always used it i guess more appealing to me is this bad...? are there advantages I am missing or performance differences...?

Comment: Well, you are basically re-inventing the wheel :)
Yes, you have to learn something new and work on something you are not used to, but this is the essence of being a developer: alway try and learn new thing and if they are better, you have gained something. I've used Doctrine ORM since I put my hands on Symfony 1 and I think it's a very good tool; you should read some documentation to help you decide what's better for you and for your application.

Comment: Hmmm i seen ORM i looked at it I just did not like all the setters and getters looks messy :P i always have a Repository class that does all the DB interaction and Factory to do all the logic. Just to this Pattern But thx I will instead try to learn ORM see how this goes :)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think you can avoid using getter and setter by defining as `public` your entities' properties; do not quote me on that because I'm not sure if it's possible or if it's not a best practice ;)

Comment: Please check the above edits I managed to get the desired result. Really appreciate your involvement in this thread. would upvote it but am a newbie on stack overflow :P apparently dont have enough points